# UserControl get Image from Resources in C#

Tags: c#, image, user-controls

I want to make UserControl with freely change image. I searched and made below code.

```
[Description("Setting the image which shows main"), Category("Custom"),
 DefaultValue(typeof(Image),"null"),
 EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor), 
 typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]

 public Image MainImage
 {
     get { return pictureBoxMain.Image; }
     set { pictureBoxMain.Image = value; }
 }
```

When I tried change image on design editor, it calls exploror. But what I want to display is not exploror, list of main project`s resource list. (just call on basic image attribute)

I thought maybe I should change below line.

```
    EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor), 
    typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

And stucked here. So please help about these.

Comment: I've tried with 

    `[Description("Setting the image which shows main"), Category("Custom"),
         DefaultValue(typeof(Image), "null")]
        public Image MainImage
        {
            get { return pictureBoxMain.Image; }
            set { pictureBoxMain.Image = value; }
        }`

and I don't have any problem with that.

Comment: rraszewski// Thanks. Done.